# Python - How to change order of instructions depending on a condition

Tags: python, if-statement

I would have a question on Python code. Is there a way to do the following :

```py
if conditon:
    A(**paramsA)
    B(**paramsB)
else:
    B(**paramsB)
    A(**paramsA)
```

Without repeating A() and B() to make it cleaner ?

Thanks !

Comment: There could be ways. But can you go more into your specific problem?

Comment: Hello @L3viathan, thanks for your answer. I need to import weights in my keras model, but sometimes, I need to add these weights before building new layers, and sometimes I need to do it after. So it is like : 
`
if condition:
   load_weights()
   add_layers()
else:
   add_layers()
   load_weights()
`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that your code is absolutely fine, we cannot do much better in terms of it being understandable. We can still get some style points though and make some enemies while at it with the following:

```
f1, f2 = [A, B][::(-1)**condition]
f1()
f2()
```

Handling the different parameters can also be facilitated with minor adjustments

```
(f1, p1), (f2, p2) = [(A, paramA), (B, paramB)][::(-1)**condition]
f1(**p1)
f2(**p2)
```

Example (assume `'foo'` and `'bar'` are the parameters and `1` and `2` the functions):

```
>>> [(1, 'foo'), (2, 'bar')][::(-1)**False]
[(1, 'foo'), (2, 'bar')]
>>> [(1, 'foo'), (2, 'bar')][::(-1)**True]
[(2, 'bar'), (1, 'foo')]
```

Of course, you do not want to have something like that for production code.

---

Note that as it currently stands, if `condition` evaluates to `True`, you get to execute `B` first. If you would like it to be the other way around, change `(-1)**(condition)` to `2*(condition)-1` **or** put a `not` in front of your `condition`.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks @Ma0, I'll stay with my code then! I was just asking as, when refactoring, if I want to change a parameter in A or in B, I will have to change it in two places, which is not that bad, but I thought I could make it better :)

Comment: Why do you? You can define the params before the if loop and then just refer to that.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap A and B in functions, then you can do:

```
if condition:
    first, second = A, B
else:
    first, second = B, A

first()
second()
```

Comment: Hi @orlp, thanks for the answer ! I just forgot to precise that A and B have different parameters, sorry for that, I'll update the post

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this:

```
flag = True


def myFuncA( a, b ):
    return a * b

def myFuncB( a, b ):
    return a -b


# define the order of calls based on flag
if flag:
    functionSequence = [myFuncA, myFuncB]
else:
    functionSequence = [myFuncB, myFuncA]

# call function in the given order
for curFunc in functionSequence:
    print( curFunc(3,4))
```

Change the value of Flag for your tests, to see if it works for you.

The big plus I see here, is that the code explains what it's doing. It first defines an order of calls based on a condition, and then executes these calls in the given order.
It's also easily expandable.